# Data Insertion repeated on Save through AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I built my first ever app using PHP Codeigniter 4 and deployed it to producation yesterday, where users save the data of their items sold. They are saved using AJAX through JQuery where after every save function, page is reloaded. Here is my code on frontend:

```
    $('form[name="transfer_record"]').submit(function (event) {
        // This will prevent form being submitted.
        event.preventDefault();
        // Call your function

        var save_date = $("#date").val();
        var save_phone_number = $("#phone_number").val();
        ...
        var save_team_lead = $("#team_lead").val();
        var save_qa_comments = $("#qa_comments").val();

        $.ajax({
        url: "<?=  base_url(). "/save_transfer_record";?>",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            save_date:save_date,
            save_phone_number:save_phone_number,
            ...
            save_team_lead:save_team_lead,
        },
        success: function (data) {
            alert('Transfer Data Saved Successfully');
            location.reload(0)
        },

        });
    });
```

Here is my code on controller in PHP:

```
public function save_transfer_record()
    {
        date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
        $usa_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

        $TransfersIBModel = new TransfersIBModel();
        if(isset($_POST)){
                $saveTransferForm = [
                    'date' => $usa_date,
                    'phone_number' => $this->request->getPost('save_phone_number'),
                    ...
                    'team_lead' => $this->request->getPost('save_team_lead'),
                ];
                $TransfersIBModel->save($saveTransferForm);
            
        }
    }
```

My PROBLEM IS: Yesterday was first day in production, and there were three instances where there were duplicate entries.

[image]

One of them, orange one, have different timestamp which maybe makes me think User entered it twice. But rest two were at same time. So, what could be the issue and how can I mitigate it.

1. How can I do ensure no duplication without making 'Phone Number' entry unique?
2. If I make 'Phone Number' unique, how can I make it work?

Please suggest me. I can try disabling button on Ajax click, but I don't think it would work because it feels like my AJAX request ran twice somehow because once it clicks, page should reload before second AJAX request, shouldn't it.
Lastly, what is the best practice now, should I hard delete duplicate entries from Table or do not show duplicate values.

Comment: Try to ask only one question at a time, please. Leave the validation issue for a separate post. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Anyway there's nothing here to indicate why/how it would have inserted the data twice, the code doesn't have any such flaw by itself. Also, you said `I can try disabling button on Ajax click, but I don't think it would work because it feels like my AJAX request ran twice somehow`...well  if the user pressed the button twice that would do it (people sometimes like to double-click (or even triple-click) on things when they don't need to), so it's probably worth implementing that anyway and see if it helps.

Comment: @ADyson thanks. I would try to ask different questions on different posts next time onwards, thanks! And I will try disabling submit button after click and see if it helps.

Comment: _“They are saved using AJAX through JQuery where after every save function, page is reloaded.”_ - what is _the point_ of making this a background request to begin with then? Why don’t you just let the form submit the normal way then?

Comment: You need to edit this one to remove the validation part of the post as well, please. Otherwise it's in danger of being closed for lacking focus.

Comment: @CBroe because in other part my application, after insertion or updation of data, performs other function, so I am JQuery quite alot and maybe also have gotten comfortable with it in the first place.